# Unchecking a checkbox and reverting to previous state c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have one page where there is a repeater which is getting populated using value from the previous page(different set of controls over there) and along with the repeater there is a checkboxlist which when selected by user changes the value in the repeater using a sql command(to be precise the value of the checked box is passed to the "select * from tablename where *checked item*" ).

Now when selecting the checkbox I am using postback to refresh the repeater. But when I want to uncheck the checked box I want it to go back to the previous repeater with values from the previous page.

I have researched about ViewState and was confused how can that help me in this case.

Below is my code for the checkbox index changed

```
protected void cc1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int i;
for (i = 0; i < cc1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (cc1.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                        //str is a random string which stores my checkbox value
                        str += " ProductName LIKE '%" + cc1.Items[i].ToString() + "%' ;";

                    RandomMethod();
                }

            }
}
```

I know that when unchecked it comes back to the same SelectedIndexChanged but what is the best approach to help user get back the previous page selected value.

PS: Not using ASP MVC. Building a Web Forms Application as per the demand of client.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Checkbox selected value in session on Next Page and Rebind Previous Repeater Checkbox list from Session.